# how does android calculate the res directories

Tags: android

I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html and I somehow left with a gap here.

1. How is the transition from `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi` to for example `String ("ldpi")` done?
2. And more importantly from `DisplayMetrics.widthPixels` and `DisplayMetrics.widthPixels` to for example `String ("large")`

For the first I can whip up a switch statement easy enough. But the 2nd one is quite more complex. Does anybody know any details? Is there a function which does it?

I even searched the source and did not find anything. But maybe i looked for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, here the correct code (you need a valid `android.content.Context` instance in attribute `context`):

```
     final android.view.WindowManager windowManager =
        (android.view.WindowManager) this.context
           .getSystemService (android.content.Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
     final android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics ();
     final android.content.res.Resources resources = this.context.getResources ();
     final android.content.res.Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration ();

     windowManager.getDefaultDisplay ().getMetrics (metrics);

     final int density = metrics.densityDpi;
     final int size =
        config.screenLayout & android.content.res.Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
     final String densityText;
     final String sizeText;

     switch (density)
     {
        case android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        {
           densityText = "ldpi";
           break;
        }
        case android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        {
           densityText = "mdpi";
           break;
        }
        case android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        {
           densityText = "hdpi";
           break;
        }
        case android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        {
           densityText = "xhdpi";
           break;
        }
        default:
        {
           densityText = "unknown";
           break;
        }
     } // switch

     switch (size)
     {
        case android.content.res.Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        {
           sizeText = "small";
           break;
        }
        case android.content.res.Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
        {
           sizeText = "normal";
           break;
        }
        case android.content.res.Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        {
           sizeText = "large";
           break;
        }
        case android.content.res.Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
        {
           sizeText = "xlarge";
           break;
        }
        default:
        {
           sizeText = "unknown";
           break;
        }
     } // switch
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the current screen density, and return a string(ie "mdpi'), and the same with size.

Have you looked at the `R.attr` constants `screenSize` and `screenDensity`? The android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenDensity) list the hard values there, but I'm almost positive you'll have to whip up a switch for both functions. It shouldn't be too bad as long as you have the values, either way.

**Update:**
Here's an idea... Check the orientation, swap if necessary, and run an if/else block based on the values in the R.attr.screenSize doc. No need to retrieve the resources that way. You might want to check the API level somewhere, though, because xlarge isn't supported on earlier versions.

```
String screenSize(int width, int height) {
    if(width > height) {
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
    }
    if(width >= 600 && height >= 800) 
        return "xlarge"; 
    else if(width >= 400 && height >= 530) 
        return "large"; 
    else if(width >= 320 && height >= 480) 
        return "normal"; 

    return "small"; 
}
```

I could be wrong, but it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Yep — that is what I want. And no I have not yet found the `R.attr` stuff. Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: “Requesting resource 0x10102ca failed because it is complex” - dam.

Comment: Well, even if you can't request the resource, you should still be able to use getMetrics() to grab your screen values and compare them to the dpi/px values on the R.attr page. Not an optimal solution, but at least you should only need to run it once. You could even do it on first post-install run and save in sharedPrefs for each device.

Comment: Yep. Simple for the density. But size far more difficult — especially since the rules are not clearly defined.

BTW: the resource seems to be a `android.content.res.TypedArray` which is a rather strange beast.

Comment: Looking deeper into ``android.content.res.TypedArray` I found  `android.content.res.Configuration` which finally hat the information needed. The rest was just a simple switch. See solution on my answer to self.

Comment: There is just one problem here: screen size depends not on real pixel but on device dependent pixel. That is the part which make it so tricky.